# Picking a date with swift UI automation

Tags: swift, datepicker, automation

In the app I'm testing there is a [date picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnHIC.png) I'm trying to automate. The wheel defaults to tomorrow and I'm attempting to change it to today's date but 2 minutes from now. Below is the code I'm using to attempt this.

```
app.pickerWheels.element(boundBy: 0).adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "Today")
app.pickerWheels.element(boundBy: 1).adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "1")
app.pickerWheels.element(boundBy: 2).adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "00")
```

(In the actual code I'm using variables and not hard coding these string)

This code works for the second and third wheel (hours and minutes) but for the first wheel it won't set the value. The test will fail and not continue past that point.

I have also tried passing today's date instead of just "Today" with the same results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DateFormatter` class with `Date` to accomplish this.

```
    // Initialize the date formatter. Set the timeZone and format. I chose hours and minutes.
    let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeZone =  NSTimeZone.local
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

    // Initialize the Date instance using a time interval since now.
    let d: Date = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 2 * 60)
    print("Current Time = \(dateFormatter.string(from: Date())), Two-Minutes-From-Now = \(dateFormatter.string(from: d))")
```

**Output:** `Current Time = 23:57, Two-Minutes-From-Now = 23:59`

A `Date` is stored as a time interval since January 1st, 1970. You can manipulate the date by adding or subtracting seconds from it. Here, I added `2 * 60` or two 60-second minutes to the current time interval (a large value represented in a double). This points to two minutes in the future.

Now, if you print the date without the formatter, it will just display the current time with no regard to your time zone. So if you want it to be accurate to your time zone, you need to set that in the formatter first. Note that it doesn't change the time, just its representation to you.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but my problem exists after I've already gotten the date and time information using Date and DateFormatter.

Perhaps I wasn't clear enough in my question but when I use `app.pickerWheels.element(boundBy: 0).adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "Today")` it doesn't move the picker wheel to the Today value.

I've tried passing it a string with the date as well in the same format (E MMM d) but the same problem persists where it fails the test.

Comment: @ZacharyHuffman Okay, I will look at this later. Thank you for explaining.